# Ajax Call hyperlink on datatable column

Tags: json, ajax, datatable

I have datatable json name = table_a.php
i have hyperlink on that file..

i can show datatable to

```
<table data-url="table_a.php"></table>
```

on that column has hyperlink. i want to process that link to ajax.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//$(document).on("click", "#stats", function (e) {
    $('#stats').click(function(e) {
        alert("a");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            alert("ab");
            url: 'update_process.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(status) {
                    var datanya = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(status));
                    $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: 'table_a.php'});

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
</script>
```

i try click link, but alert never show.

table_a.php :

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/json');
include '../koneksi.php';

$select = mysql_query("select * from tb_pemesanan where no_meja='$_GET[meja]'");
$row=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))

{
    $select1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_pemesanan where id_pemesanan='$row[id_pemesanan]' AND status='Sedang di proses'");
    $status='0';
    if(mysql_num_rows($select1)== 0) {
        $status="<a class='btn btn-success' href='#'><b>Sudah di antar <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></b></a>";
    }else{


    $status="<a id='stats' class='btn btn-primary' href='proses.php'>
    <b>Sedang di proses <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass'></span></b></a>";
}

$arrayx=array(  "status"=>$status );

$rows[] = $arrayx;

}
echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Comment: please show your `PHP` code.

Comment: i have add table_a.php

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating your `table_a.php` code as below. You can find some comments for what changes I have done in the program and the reason for it.

```
<?php
  header('content-type:application/json');
  include '../koneksi.php';

  $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_pemesanan WHERE no_meja = '$_GET[meja]'");
  $row = array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $select1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_pemesanan WHERE id_pemesanan = '$row[id_pemesanan]' AND status = 'Sedang di proses'");
    $status = '0';
    if(mysql_num_rows($select1) == 0) {
      $status = "<a class='btn btn-success' href='#'><b>Sudah di antar <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></b></a>";
    } else {
      // id = "stats" changed to class="stats"
      $status = "<a class='btn btn-primary stats' href='proses.php'>
        <b>Sedang di proses <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass'></span></b></a>";
    }

    $arrayx = array("status"=>$status);

    $rows[] = $arrayx;

  }
  echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Also Change your `javascript` :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // $(document).on("click", "#stats", function (e) {
    // jquery counts only first id, so if you want to apply the same for all buttons you should change that id to class name
    $('.stats').click(function(e) {
      alert("a");
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        alert("ab");
        url: 'update_process.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(status) {
          var datanya = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(status));
          $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: 'table_a.php'});
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  })
</script>
```

Try it. If it's still not giving proper output, Please input me with your php script output.